# Meeting invitation email from Microsoft teams on Thunderbird / Ubuntu without date / time info

Tags: thunderbird, microsoft-teams

When I receive an email from a team which is using MS Teams for collaboration, in my Ubuntu / Thunderbird, I can see the meeting link, phone number, conference ID etc.

But I cannot find the date and time of the meeting.

I'm an external, so I cannot use meeting options for this meeting to see the date/time.
Is there any other way to find out when the meeting is (without asking a team member with Windows / Outlook)?

Comment: seems that your thunderbird does not handle the ICS as a meeting invitation, I stopped using thunderbird a long while ago, but wasn't there a calendar plugin? The email should have an attachment with the meeting details and was it lightning or what to handle calendar events? sorry that I am not more helpful, but maybe it will help you to investigate yourself. first check the received email if it has an attachment....

Comment: From Google calendar / hangouts I can see the ICS attachment and Thunderbird displays the info nicely.
From MS there is no ICS attachment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR: Install the Lightning calendar extension for Thunderbird with `sudo apt-get install lightning` and restart.

A little bit of background:

There used to be an add-on providing this functionality, https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/sfoa/ .

Unfortunately that add-on stopped working. The add-on repository mentions an old Thunderbird bug report at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=505024 which gives a bit of background to the origin of this behavior.

From Thunderbird 78 the Lightning add-on will become integrated and this should become a non-issue.

Comment: The package for Ubuntu 20.04 is called `xul-ext-lightning`.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much.

Comment: `xul-ext-lightning` works also with Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: As of Thunderbird 108, this is **still** an issue. (or again)